# stdin in Heroku console while deploying the app

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

I've configured Heroku auto-deploy from GitHub for my Node.js server. While my server is starting up I need to insert a secret code (SMS from my mobile phone) to the console. How can I do it with Heroku?